# Setting TEXINPUTS

Tags: environment-variables

Am using the following command to set TEXINPUTS where I have my style files

```
gungadin_trk="${HOME}/Opstk/bin/gungadin-1.0"
chilkat_trk="${gungadin_trk}/typex/chilkat//"
export TEXINPUTS=".:${chilkat_trk}:${TEXINPUTS}"
```

When I do

```
echo $TEXINPUTS
```

I get the directory repeated twice.  What could be the cause for this ?

```
.:/home/hagbard/Opstk/bin/gungadin-1.0/typex/chilkat//:.:/home/hagbard/Opstk/bin/gungadin-1.0/typex/chilkat//:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a bash question unrelated to tex

`export TEXINPUTS=".:${chilkat_trk}:${TEXINPUTS}"`

prepends

`.:/home/hagbard/Opstk/bin/gungadin-1.0/typex/chilkat//:`

to whatever was the (unshown) current value of `TEXINPUTS`  which clearly already had this directory at the front.

This could happen if for example the original lines were in `.bashrc` and you started a nested shell as you are adding the local directory again at every shell that is started.

Comment: Have found the place where the command was called prematurely.